# How to add a new service to scrapyd from current project

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I am trying to run multiple spiders at once and I made my own custom command in scrapy. Now I am trying to run that command through srapyd. I tried to add it as a new service to my scrapd.conf but it throws an error saying there is no such module.

`Failed to load application: No module named XXXX`

Also, I cannot set a relative path. 
My question is how can I add my custom command as a service or fire it through scrapyd. I have something like this in my scrapyd.conf:

`updateoutdated.json = currentdirectory.myproject.commands`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?